# Issue with If Statement in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I am having difficulty with an if statement in jekyll

```
{% if site.disqus_account %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
  function disqus_config() { this.experiment.enable_scroll_container = true; }
  var disqus_shortname = "{{ site.disqus_account }}"; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
{% endif %}
```

The above code is fully functional. I added the disqus_account variable to my yaml configuration file and it works fine. However. If I do site.comments or post.comments -

```
{% if site.disqus_account and site.comments %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
  function disqus_config() { this.experiment.enable_scroll_container = true; }
  var disqus_shortname = "{{ site.disqus_account }}"; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
{% endif %}
```

The above then stops working and nothing is displayed. In my post I am declaring

```
---
layout: post
comments: true
---
```

I have restarted my jekyll server several times. There are no errors when I compile my site. Why would my addition of an and statement to check if comments are enabled for that post prevent the entire thing from loading?

I am following the article located at https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472138-jekyll-installation-instructions in order to setup disqus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article referenced at https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472138-jekyll-installation-instructions is incorrect. The yaml variables declared in the blog post are located in page.comments and not site.comments or post.comments.